# Подскажите как правильно отправить запрос requests.post

Tags: python, post, requests

Подскажите как правильно сделать post запрос в python,
[image: запрос от браузера]

```
param ={
    
    'bill_orders':[{'0':'201228T1334859633'}],
    'game':'csgo'
}
rs = requests.post(urls,json=param, headers=headers)
```

Comment: `'bill_orders':['201228T1334859633']`

Comment: Спасибо большое,это сработало!и за 0 не мог понять)